# How do I emulate the curl -F option in node.js request

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am trying to post some data to the sensiolabs security api from a node.js AWS lambda.  The only documentation on the sensiolabs site documents how to do this for a curl command.  It documents the call as
 `curl -H "Accept: text/plain" https://security.sensiolabs.org/check_lock -F lock=@/path/to/composer.lock`.

I am trying to do this from an AWS lambda where I have the composer.json is in an S3 bucket.  I can read the bucket and get the contents of the file as a string but I can not figure out how to properly create the node.js request object to emulate the above curl command.  Here is my latest attempt:

```
exports.check_lockfile = function(data) {
  var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
  var s = new Readable;
  s.push(data); // the string you want
  s.push(null); // indicates end-of-file basically - the end of the stream

  var promise = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
      var request = require('request');
      var url = 'https://security.sensiolabs.org/check_lock';

      var req = request.post({
        headers: {
          "Accept": "text/plain"
        },
        url: url
      }, function(err, resp, body) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error!');
          reject();
        } else {
          console.log(resp.statusCode);
          console.log('body is ' + body);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
          resolve();
        }
      });
      var form = req.form();
      form.append('lock', s);
    });
  return promise;
};
```

But I no matter what I try I get malformed request or bad request `{"error": "no lock}`.

Answer (score 1):

curl -F is equivalent to upload file using multipart/form-data.

I modified the code and run it and I got this return: 
**200
body is Security Report**

Here is the code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

var url = 'https://security.sensiolabs.org/check_lock';

var formData = {lock: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/composer.lock')};

var req = request.post(
    {
        headers: {
          "Accept": "text/plain",
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        url: url,
        formData: formData
    }, function(err, resp, body) 
    {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error!');
        } else {
          console.log(resp.statusCode);
          console.log('body is ' + body);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
        }
    }
);
```

Note: you may need to update the path of 'composer.lock' file, on my test I put it on same folder which contain js file.

Here is a screenshot after running the above code with node command:
[image]